# How to make requests to share Google Custom search?

Tags: google-custom-search

People are sending me emails to share my Google Custom searches -- apparently through Google Sites. I cannot understand this because I have blocked all accesses to Google products such as Blogger, Google Sites, iGoogle Gadgets and Google apps. How can people make this kind of requests to share the GCSs?